# For a directory file descriptor dfd, can I prevent traversing up as in openat(dfd, "..", ...)?

Tags: linux, permissions, security, c, file-descriptors

I have a user `$service` with a directory `/srv/$service/subdir`. `/srv/$service` has a mode of 0700, i.e. it's only accessible by `$service`. That user can open a directory file descriptor to `…/subdir` or any directory below it using:

```c
int fd = open("…/subdir", O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC | O_DIRECTORY, 0);
```

Using Unix domain sockets I can share that file descriptor with another process running with another effective user ID, that would otherwise be unable access this folder. So far everything works just fine.

**But:** The other process is able to invoke `openat(fd, "../somefile", …)` to open `somefile` in `$service`'s home directory. I have to trust that other process not to do that.

**How** can I prevent that scenario? Did I miss some flag to the first call of `open()` that would prevent that directory traversal? Is it possible use some `fcntl(fd, …)` invocation to do that? Or is there some other method?

Comment: How much control over the whole setup do you have/how much can you modify it? Just as an example, would bind-mounting `subdir` somewhere else and having the other process use that mount be an option? Also, I assume you're asking about a solution using pure discretionary access control mechanisms, thus no SELinux and the like, right?

Comment: @TooTea, putting `subdir` in a dedicated path outside of $service's home directory works. `/dir1/dir2/subdir` (chmod 0111 dir1 [chown root], chmod 0700 dir2 [chown $service]), but I'd still be interested if there was another solution that preserves original file hierarchy without an ln. Adding as SELinux rule to kill anyone who accesses $service's files would most likely work, too.

Comment: Please clarify your scenario, or even better show some reproducible example, so people less intellectually gifted (like me) could have a grasp of it. AFAIK, if a user doesn't have execute permission to a directory (and its parent), `openat(open_fd_to_that_dir, "../somefile", ...)` will just FAIL.

Answer (score 1):

> But: The other process **[running as a different user]** is able to invoke `openat(fd, "../somefile", …)` to open somefile in `$service`'s home directory.

No, it isn't. For that it should have execute permission to `fd` and its parent directory, but the parent directory mode is `0700`, allowing only the owner to traverse it.